# C - Iterate the given json array of json objects

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I have a below array of json objects. I need to iterate this array of json objects and the "id" from each json object, if the id matched, I should remove the json from array and add the new 
array.

So far I did this,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jansson.h>
#include <time.h>


int main()
{

    char* rfid_json_dict = NULL;
    json_t *root = json_object();
    json_t *json_arr = json_array();


    char id[] ="1";
    char value[] =  "D0D0-0000-0000-0000-0001-A431";
    char *buf;


    json_object_set_new( root, "id", json_string(id) );
    json_object_set_new( root, "value", json_string(value) );


    json_array_append( json_arr, root );   
    buf = json_dumps(json_arr ,0);
    printf("JSON:::%s\n",buf );



    for(int i = 0; i < buf.size(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject objects = buf.getJSONObject(i);
        printf("value ::: %s", objects);
    }
}
```

How to iterate the json array in C for this given statements?

Comment: How do you compile? `char *buf;` -> `buf.size()` and `buf.getJSONObject(i);` is not proper C syntax.

Comment: https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON#arrays have a look at this documentation.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio, yup you are right. Those are for JS. I need similar kind of functionality in c.